# EditText с частично изменяемым текстом

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать EditText Подобного вида
http://clip2net.com/s/4MoVrB

что бы при вводе изменялось только значение справа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поиграться с TextWatcher. Что-то типа:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){ 
    String left = "left text ";
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
         if (s.length() < = left.length()) {
             s = left;
         }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}  
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Но тогда текст справа не будет прилепляться к правому краю. Проще всего взять TextView и EditText.

Comment: Собственно так и сделал, взял TextView и EditText + RelativeLayout